# (Java) How does one manipulate a variable of a custom object when said object in in an array?

Tags: java, processing

Say I have created a custom object, Tile, like so

```
public class Tile {
  String name;
  int color;
  public Tile(String n, int c){
    name = n;
    color = c;
  }
}
```

and I create an array of these Tile objects

```
Tile[][] board = new Tile[8][8];
```

how would I be able to give each Tile a name and color? What syntax would I use in order to give the Tile at board[0][0] the name "A1" and the color 255? Thank you.

Comment: `board[0][0].name = "A1";`, assuming you've actually populated the array.

Comment: A lot of times it’s better to make setter or mutator methods, such as Tile.setObject(String name, short color); (At least in my opinion)

Answer (score 0):

While `Tile[][] board = new Tile[8][8];` creates a 2D array of tiles, it does not create the tiles themselves.

You can add tiles individually like:

```
Tile[][] board = new Tile[8][8];
board[0][0] = new Tile("A1", 255);
```

If you want to fill the board with tiles, try using a nested loop:

```
Tile[][] board = new Tile[8][8];

int counter = 0;

for( int row = 0; row < board.length; row++ ) {
    for( int column = 0; column < board[row].length; column++ ) {
        board[row][column] = new Tile("A" + counter++, 255);
    }
}
```

The code above would fill in the board giving the tiles unique names ("A0", "A1", etc...).

If you want to change the name of a tile in the board after it has been added, you can access it like `board[0][0].name = "A1";` (Same for the color value). Another way you could change the values is by adding a setter method in the Tile class.